# How to read excel file in selenium

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, crosstab

I am trying to compare 2 excel sheet. My excel can contain any type of data i tried this code.I am using POI to compare the excel data. But when I run the above code it give null pointer issue & reads only few cells of the sheet. Also some time it gives an error can not read string as numeric value.

```
        int numberOfSheets = workbook1.getNumberOfSheets();
         for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++)

        {
         int lastRowNum2 = workbook1.getSheetAt(i).getLastRowNum();
         for (int j = 0; j < lastRowNum2; j++)

        {

         short lastCellNum = workbook1.getSheetAt(i).getRow(j).getLastCellNum();
         for (int k = 0; k < lastCellNum; k++)

         {
               Iterator<Row> rowIterator1 = sheet1.iterator();
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator2 = sheet2.iterator();

                while (rowIterator1.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIterator1.next();
                         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
                    case BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                        break;
                    case NUMERIC:
                        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                            System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue());
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        }
                        break;
                    case FORMULA:
                        System.out.print(cell.getCellFormula());
                        break;
                    case BLANK:
                        System.out.println("This is blank");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.print("This is default");
                }
                    System.out.print("\t");
                    }

                     System.out.println(workbook1.getSheetAt(i).getRow(j).getCell(k).getStringCellValue()
                 + workbook2.getSheetAt(i).getRow(j).getCell(k).getStringCellValue());  

         try {
             Assert.assertEquals(workbook1.getSheetAt(i).getRow(j).getCell(k),
                     workbook2.getSheetAt(i).getRow(j).getCell(k));
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users">How much research effort is expected?</a> This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Selenium is not used to access Excel files.

Comment: Please read [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) as well as [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) and the "Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells" below.